# How does one import an npm module into a Vue.js application?

Tags: vue.js, pdf

I would like to import pdf-lib into my vue.js application.

1. Installed using npm

> npm install --save pdf-lib

2. Imported into my component like this,

```
import _ from "@pdf-lib";

export default {
    data() {
```

3. I get the following error message,

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pdf-lib' in

Comment: There's not enough details. Generally it's done like that and it should work. Make sure that pdf-lib really exists in package.json and node_modules.

Comment: Yes, it exists in package.json and node_modules. It exists as node_modules/@pdf-lib and     "@pdf-lib/fontkit": "^1.1.1",

Comment: Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: This is what I get when I do npm install,

npm WARN uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@2.2.0 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ npm@7.24.1
+ install@0.13.0
+ @pdf-lib/fontkit@1.1.1
added 259 packages from 148 contributors and audited 1196 packages in 23.136s

Comment: Try to remove node modules and reinstall, this is the only thing that can be suggested here. The question cannot be answered because there's no such problem in general. If the problem persists, please, provide a way to reproduce it, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please post your `package.json` too.

Comment: Here is my package.json
{dependencies:{@pdf-lib/fontkit:"^1.1.1",axios:"^0.21.4",bootstrap:"^3.4.1",install:"^0.13.0",npm:"^7.24.1",uglify-es:"^3.3.9",uglifyjs-webpack-plugin:"^2.2.0",v-tooltip:"^2.1.3",vue:"^2.5.11",vue-axios:"^3.3.7",vue-resource:"^1.5.3",vue-router:"^3.5.2",vue-toasted:"^1.1.28"},devDependencies:{babel-core:"^6.26.0",babel-loader:"^7.1.2",babel-preset-env:"^1.6.0",babel-preset-stage-3:"^6.24.1",cross-env:"^5.0.5",css-loader:"^0.28.7",file-loader:"^1.1.4",vue-loader:"^13.0.5",vue-template-compiler:"^2.4.4",webpack:"^3.6.0",webpack-dev-server:"^2.9.1"}

Comment: @EstusFlask I have already tried removing and adding node_modules/ I will try to reproduce using mcve.

Comment: There is no `pdf-lib` in package.json you posted. Even if there were, you can't import it from `@pdf-lib` because there's no such package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pdf-lib . `@` is for NPM scopes, not just something that can be added arbitrarily.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I had to do a npm install pdf-lib (without @) to get it working.